# Nodejs + Passport + MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js, passport-twitter

I'm trying to figure out how to use nodejs + Passport + MySQL.  It seems as though just about every tutorial out there is using mongoDB and I don't want to do that.  In fact some quick searches of this type will yield web pages like (http://nodejsrocks.blogspot.com/2012/04/nodejs-expressjs-mysql.html) and a youtube video that is a guy (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGBbMVJx3h0) doing nothing but loging in, and who knows what he is really using, but the page has had 3K + views.  I'd hope that some of the developers would look at that and say maybe there is a use for something like a comprehensive non MVC type of thing with MySQL.  My reason for this is I am trying to get iOS and Android capabilities only and have no need for a large scaffolding overhead.  Just the DB and server side scripting handling the queries and returning JSON objects to the phones.

So, that being said, can someone who has had real experience with this please help me out(And the rest of the world trying to do similar things without any in-depth tutorials, because we aren't using mongoDB and full blown scaffolding).

The tables I have set up for a 'TwitterStrategy' are users(id (PK), username, email, salt, password), and twitterusers(id (PK), name, screenname, location, description, url, img, token, tokensecret).

Here is the code I am trying to get going from a single main.js file.  I know this is not best practices, and I plan to clean it up later, but for now, I would like to understand what I am missing and get things working.  It would be extremely appreciated if someone can help, and I'm SURE others would find this very useful as well.  Thanks.

```
var http  = require('http'),
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    url   = require('url'),
    crypto = require('crypto'),
    express = require('express'),
    flash = require('connect-flash'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;

var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : "****",
    user     : "****",
    password : "****",
    port     : '****',
    database : '****' 
});

// Connect the connection to DB and throw error if exists
db.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) { 
        console.error('Error connecting to db');
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Database connected');
});

var TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "****";
var TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "****";

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback'},
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        //db.query(SELECT ........ FROM ...... WHERE ........, function (err, user){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (!err && user != null){
                done(null, result);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializeUser: ' + user.id);
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ' + id, function(err, result) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
        console.log(result);
        }
        if (!err) {
            done(null, result);
        } else {
            done(err, null);
        }
    });
});

var app = express();

app.set(function(){

    // app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); // Definitely for some views which aren't being used here
    // app.set('view engine', 'jade'); // Using jade for views, not used
    // app.use(express.favicon()); // Not really sure this is important, should be web only
    app.use(express.logger('dev')); // Again, not really sure this is important
    app.use(express.bodyParser()); // Have no idea what this is used for
    app.use(express.methodOverride()); // Same no Fn clue
    app.use(express.cookieParser('what the F'));
    app.use(express.session());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(flash());
    // app.use(app.router); // Here again we are defining our routes in main, so shouldn't need this.
    // app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

});

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log('url: ' + req.url); 

    var params = url.parse(req.url, true)
    var path = params.pathname;
    if (path == '/signup') {
        console.log("User signing up");
        onSignUp(params, res);
    } else if (path == '/signin') {
        console.log("User signing in");
        onSignIn(params, res);
    } else if (path == '/auth/twitter'){
        passport.authenticate('twitter'),
        function(req, res){
            console.log('Twitter User Created or Signed In');
        }
    }
});

//Keep server alive and listening to requests with DB connected also
server.listen(3000);
```

Am I missing another auth table? What is it that I need to put in the MySQL statement where the dots are so that I can find the user, and what parameters are being passed from the user request to get the query going, i.e. what is this oauth ID I have seen in tutorials that is getting passed from what seems to be the user to twitter for authorization?  Also, what should I be expecting from this callback from Twitter? Anyway, I'll be glad to post all of this somewhere for everyone else to look at once I have a solution made so that all of us using MySQL and node don't get left out and have to search google to find something that seems as though it should be readily available, instead of copies of the same exact nodejs + mongoDB + express tutorial (with many that are out of date except for the scotch io, which looks very good if you wanna use mongo...might I add instances over at Amazon run about $279 estimated per month on the low end) that is floating around and being redistributed by nearly anyone with a "tutorial" out there.  Thanks again.

Comment: This is an old post by now, but in case someone comes by here in the future, have a look at this Github project: https://github.com/manjeshpv/node-express-passport-mysql

Comment: [Javascript Authentication using Passport, MySQl, and Express](http://denisahac.xyz/javascript-authentication-using-passport-mysql-and-express/)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping strategy function under `process.nextTick`, e.g.,

```
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    callbackURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback'},
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function(){
        // this is where you put logic to check the profile sent from twitter already in your DB or not, 
        // its totally up to you whether you keep a separate auth table for it or not
        // NB: there will be some unique value in profile that can be used for next references
        db.query(SELECT ........ FROM ...... WHERE ........, function (err, user){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (!err && user != null){
                done(null, result);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        })
        });
       });
    }
));
```

you also have to have a route for accepting the callback, e.g.,

```
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', function(req, res, next) {
   passport.authenticate('twitter', 
                           { }, 
                           function(err, user) {
                            // the result you send from the strategy function will be here
                            // do anything you like with the user send 
                           }

                         )(req, res, next);
});
```

Hope it makes things clearer.